# Codeigniter - Placing a <?php base_url(); ?> as a source inside a controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to put a link inside a source inside my controller.

Code:

```
$marker['icon'] = "<?php echo base_url('assets/dist/GMapMarkers/paleblue_MarkerH.png') ?>;"
```

but it doesn't load. I am guessing that echoing the base URL inside a controller won't work. Is there any other method to do this?

Comment: Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `base_url` just returns string, you can assign this string to a variable and `echo` this variable later:

```
$marker['icon'] = base_url('assets/dist/GMapMarkers/paleblue_MarkerH.png');
echo $marker['icon'];
```

Answer (score 2):

**base_url** is a function, you call it with param (string). Function combine base configs and your string, and returns completed url.

```
$marker['icon'] = base_url('assets/dist/GMapMarkers/paleblue_MarkerH.png');
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found which is a modification on the other answers and shorter:

```
$marker['icon'] = $this->config->base_url('assets/dist/GMapMarkers/blue_MarkerL.png');
```

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant about shorter. Perhaps you can edit your answer to make that clearer. I edited it to make it clear that it's an answer.

Comment: i meant, instead of using this:  $marker['icon'] = $this->config->base_url(); , 
$marker['icons'] = base_url(); is shorter.